# query on user record not returning any records when logged in as partner community user

Tags: soql, community

The below query is returning zero records when i log in as partner community user. This query is being execute from a helper class which is being called from a trigger. The helper class and trigger are running in system mode.

Query below:

```
NameSet='Developer Test'
List<User> userList = new List<User>();
        userList = [Select Id, name from User where name in :nameSet]
system.debug('### SOQL Query is ####'+''+ [Select Id, name from User where name in :nameSet]);
```

when i use debug log for the user, the above soql query is not even being printed in the debuglog

Let me know what the issue could be.

Comment: How is your class declared `with sharing` or `without sharing`? What is the OWD of User object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the OWD for the User object? The default access for External Access is Private.

Try changing it to Read-Only.